# Get selected product from a datalist in visual studio and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net

Im trying to learn asp and C# and trying to make a webshop.

I have a working dataset and datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PicURL") %>' runat="server" ID="PicURLImage" Width="150px" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="AddProduct" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' runat="server" OnClick="AddProduct_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want to press this linkbutton and then It eventually should add this product to a shoppingcart. But right now I just need help to get the selected product row from the datalist that is using a datasource that is connected to the database.

When I click the link I want to execute this code:

```
Data.DataSet1.ProductDataTable pTable = new Data.DataSet1TableAdapters.ProductTableAdapter().GetDataByCategory();

protected void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add product to the shopping cart
        //Class      //method           
        ShoppingCart.Instance.AddItem(THIS IS HE QUESTION I NEED HELP WITH!);


        // Redirect the user to view their shopping cart
        Response.Redirect("ViewCart.aspx");

    }

 public void AddItem(int productId)
    {
        // Create a new item to add to the cart
        CartItem newItem = new CartItem(productId);

        // If this item already exists in our list of items, increase the quantity
        // Otherwise, add the new item to the list
        if (Items.Contains(newItem))
        {
            foreach (CartItem item in Items)
            {
                if (item.Equals(newItem))
                {
                    item.Quantity++;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newItem.Quantity = 1;
            Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

Do you guys need more information? Do you have any tips or suggestions? Im stuck >__<

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this.

add CommandName attribute to your button (you will not longer need the OnClick event handler for the button) and add event handler for ItemCommand on DataList:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellSpacing="10" OnItemCommand="Item_Command">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PicURL") %>' runat="server" ID="PicURLImage" Width="150px" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="AddProduct" ID="AddProduct" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' runat="server" OnClick="AddProduct_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Change your c# to define Item_Command

```
void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.CommandName == "AddProduct")
   {
      // e.Item.ItemIndex is the selected index
      // DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex] will return the product id
   }
}
```

Also you can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further details.

Comment: But doesent this take the index of the datalist, so index number one is the first product in the datalist and so on. I want to get the index from the product from the database! Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are looking for.  "Index from the product from the database"  is that a field in the database?  Your question was "I just need help to get the selected product row from the datalist"

Comment: Sry for the blurry question. I have a table in sql named "products" that I want  to access. I want to click on selected datalist object and somehow get the information from the product table row that is stored in the database. So I can use that info to put in a shoppingcart since im making a webshop :)

Comment: I updated the C# code in my answer.  Please look at the second comment.

Comment: It acually worked, Thanks alot you really made my day! Fantastic :D

Answer (score -1):

```
 protected void Btn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
 {
     DataListItem dli = (DataListItem)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
     int indx = dli.ItemIndex;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like it could be a good answer. But can you provide some explanation for this code snippet?